# Which access control system is right for dynamic multi layer security check?

Tags: permissions, access-control, user-permissions, rbac, abac

I have RESTful APIs and in microservice architecture. Such as -

- Auth service
- User service
- Product service
- More ...

Currently, I am validating request via JWT token which can be obtained from Auth service. Now, time has come to implement an access control system.

It's an internal tool application (pretty complex) and my primary thought was to use RBAC (Role-based access control) but the application isn't traditional. In application, User A can pair up with another User B and once pair up completed, based on User B's settings User A can perform various action.

So permissions aren't static and they're based on other variables. So should I go for ABAC/PBAC system? Any suggestions?

**Thoughts on ABAC**

- Subjects - Who is sending request e.g User A
- Object - Accessing what? e.g Module A
- Actions - Read or write? e.g Read GET request
- Environment - condition e.g for which User? (User B)

Answer (score 3):

My biased answer is: yes you should :-) (I work for [Axiomatics](https://www.axiomatics.com) and all we do is PBAC/ABAC and have done so for 15 years).

Note that PBAC and ABAC in this context are the same. PBAC is actually a much older concept. We've been using policies in many places e.g. network access control or SDDL in the past.

The main benefit of attribute-based access control for you ([abac](/questions/tagged/abac)) is that it will give you the freedom to adapt your access control policies over time without having to rewrite your application. Effectively, you decouple / externalize authorization from the application.

The following shows the basic architectural flow in ABAC whereby a component (the PEP) intercepts the business flow and converts it into an authorization flow (*Can Alice view record 123?*).

[image: Attribute Based Access Control Architecture]

Policies can be written in [xacml](/questions/tagged/xacml) or [alfa](/questions/tagged/alfa). I prefer the latter since its syntax is super lightweight (read more on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALFA_(XACML))).

For instance you could write:

```
namespace com.acme{
    /**
     * Tutorial 101 - a flat approach using 4 rules
     */
     policyset recordsAccess{
         apply firstApplicable
         /**
          * Records access control
          */
          policy records{
              target clause object.objectType == "record"
              apply firstApplicable
              /**
               * R1 - A manager can view any records
               */
               rule managersView{
                   target clause user.role == "manager" and action.actionId == "view"
                   permit
               }
              /**
               * R2 - An employee can view a record in their own department
               */
               rule employeesView{
                   target clause user.role == "employee" and action.actionId == "view"
                   condition user.department == record.department
                   permit
               }
              /**
               * R3 - An employee can edit a record they own, if it is in draft mode
               */
               rule employeeEdit{
                   target clause user.role == "employee" and action.actionId == "edit" and record.status == "draft"
                   condition  com.acme.record.owner == com.acme.user.employeeId 
                   permit
               }
              /**
               * R4 - A manager can publish a record if the record is in final 
               * mode and it belongs to a employee below that manager.
               */
               rule managerPublish{
                   target clause user.role == "manager" and action.actionId == "publish"
                   condition stringIsIn(stringOneAndOnly(com.acme.record.owner),com.acme.user.subordinate)
                   permit
               }
          }
     }
}
```